# Where to Load ContentControl Styles in Avalonia Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a ContentControl/TemplatedControl written in Avalonia Class Library, and the styles defined in a file.

To load the styles, in WPF, you'd need to add AssemblyInfo.cs with this hack

```
using System.Windows;

[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
                                     //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                     // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
                                              //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                              // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

Now with Avalonia... what's the way to do it?

EDIT: Is the answer that the client must register the files manually in App.xaml?

```
<Application.Styles>
    <StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/DefaultTheme.xaml"/>
    <StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/Accents/BaseLight.xaml"/>
    <StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid/Themes/Default.xaml"/>
</Application.Styles>
```

but then -- what if I want to display multiple such controls with different styles? I could have a property on the control to choose the theme or the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles defined in the `App.xaml` are global, so all controls will be using them. However, it is possible to change them at runtime. In your case you could start with creating a styles dictionary to simplify things and add all those `StyleInclude` there, so your `Application.Styles` have only one entry:

```
<Application.Styles>
    <StyleInclude Source="avares://YourAssembly/Path/YourStyles1.xaml"/>
</Application.Styles>
```

Now, let's say you want to change this resource to `YourStyles2.xaml` in the code.

```
private static StyleInclude CreateStyle(string url)
{
    var self = new Uri("resm:Styles?assembly=YourAssembly");
    return new StyleInclude(self)
    {
        Source = new Uri(url)
    };
}

private void SetStyles()
{
   var newStyles = CreateStyle("avares://YourAssembly/Path/YourStyles2.xaml");
   Avalonia.Application.Current.Styles[0] = newStyles;
}
```